# 2 Dimentional Array VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, arrays, arraylist

How i can convert this array to an UNLIMITED range array?

```
Dim multiArray(2, 2) As String 
multiArray(0, 0) = "item1InRow1" 
multiArray(0, 1) = "item2InRow1" 
multiArray(1, 0) = "item1InRow2" 
multiArray(1, 1) = "item2InRow2"
```

I Tryed:

```
Dim multiArray(,) As String
```

but i not have succeeded

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make an 2D Dynamic Array in VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378353/make-an-2d-dynamic-array-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable like this. the value of n can be assigned from user/some logic.

```
Dim n As Integer = 2
Dim str As String(,) = New String(n - 1, n - 1) {}
```

Comment: Is that going to preserve his pre-existing data?

Comment: str is assigning a new value. So it will start from index 0. So may i know what is your exact requirement ?

Comment: It looks like since he accepted your answer that he was asking how to programically create a new multi-dimensional array not redimension an existing. +1 for a good answer

Answer (score 2):

Arrays by their nature have a finite size, the only way to change it is to [Redim / Preserve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) the array which can be quite costly(see this [link](http://www.ehow.com/facts_7841787_pros-cons-redim-statement.html)) and only redimensions the last dimemension. You may want to look into using something like an [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) or another one of the [collection classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.aspx) like the article suggests.